# Find if $\sum \frac1{(n^3-2\pi)}$ diverges or converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Using no tests besides nth Term and Comparison Test I need to determinate whether the series converges or diverges to $\pm \infty $:

> $$\sum \dfrac1{(n^3-2\pi)}$$

The thing is no matter what I do I can't satisfy any of the rules for any test given. The limit is $0$ so by nth Term it proves nothing, and for Comparison Test I wanted to use the fact that since 
$$n^3-2\pi \leq n^3$$  then
$$\dfrac 1{(n^3-2\pi)}\geq 1/n^3 $$ so we set them as $b(n)$ and $a(n)$

where

$\dfrac 1{n^3}$ is convergent but proves nothing since I could use it only if $a(n)$ was divergent.

$\dfrac 1{n^3-2\pi}$ is divergent but again proves nothing since I could use it only if $b(n)$ was convergent.

Maybe I was wrong at some point or I'm missing something? If I put absolute value for the whole sum to what do I make it less equal to? Do I treat $\pi$ like a constant for that case or?

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit I appreciate you help with editing and improving post on the site. Let me just mention that it is recommended to avoid using `\dfrac`, `\dbinom`, `\displaystyle` and similar constructions in the title. More details can be found here: [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9687).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for letting me know ! Will keep it in mind the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\geq3$, $$\frac1{n^3-2\pi}<\frac1{n^2+n},$$ as is easily seen by comparing the derivatives of both sides. Furthermore, $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1{n^2+n}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}=\frac13$$ converges, which implies that our original sum does too. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 6):

*Hint:* For $n \ge 3$, we have $n^3-2\pi > n^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Another option: for $n\ge3$, $n^3-2\pi>\frac12n^3$.